# Fluctuation-dissipation theorem and Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, fluctuation-dissipation

Is there any connection between [fluctuation dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) and [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations)? They are often described together under [linear response theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_response_function) but I do not see any exact connection (like one being special case of another).

Comment: Kubo uses Kramers-Kronig on p. 22 of his paper [The Fluctuation-Dissipation Theorem](http://th.if.uj.edu.pl/~gudowska/dydaktyka/kubo.pdf), but only once.

Comment: Fluctuations and dissipations are the real and imaginary parts of the response function, and are related to each other via Kramers-Kronig relations. The general mathematical statement behind everything is the Hilbert transform. See these key-words (Kramers-Kronig / fluctuation-dissipation / Hilbert transform) on Wikipedia, and answer your question yourself :-)

Answer (score 5):

Kramers-Kronig relations can be understood as requirement that $\operatorname{Re} \chi(\omega)$ is an even function, while $\operatorname{Im} \chi(\omega)$ is an odd function - see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386605/what-is-the-intuition-behind-kramers-kronig-relations) and the [linked Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations#Related_proof_from_the_time_domain) therein.

The general Fluctuation-Dissipation theorem usually written as proportionality between fluctuation energy spectrum and imaginary part of fourier of responce function: $$S_x(\omega) = \frac{2kT}{\omega}\operatorname{Im} \chi(\omega)$$
While the lhs of the above expression $S_x(\omega)=\langle x(\omega)x^*(\omega)\rangle$ is easily interpreted as "fluctuation" part. It is not at all obvious that $\operatorname{Im} \chi(\omega)$ is related to "dissipation". The standard derivation below uses the the Kramers-Kronig symmetry requirements and links $\operatorname{Im} \chi(\omega)$ to the dissipation of the system.

Assuming that we have the observable $x(t)$, the stochastic external force $f(t)$ and the response function $\chi(t)$ are linked via:
$$ x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\tau\; \chi(t-\tau)f(\tau)$$

We want to compute dissipated power $f(t)\dot x(t)$ under periodic force $f(t) = A \cos\Omega t$. To do that we first simplify the expression for $\dot{x}(t)$.
Taking the derivative gives us factor $-i\omega$ and integration over $\tau$ gives a double-$\delta$ fourier transform of the cosine:

$$\dot{x}(t) = \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}(-i\omega) e^{-i\omega t}\chi(\omega) \pi A[\delta(\omega - \Omega) + \delta(\omega+\Omega)]$$

Integrating out the $\delta$s we'll get:
$$\dot{x}(t) =-iA\frac\Omega2\left[\chi(\Omega)e^{-i\Omega t} - \chi(-\Omega)e^{i\Omega t} \right]$$

Now we multiply by $f(t)$ and average over one period:

$$\langle W\rangle = \frac{\Omega}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/\Omega}dt\;f(t)\dot{x}(t) = -\frac{i A^2\Omega}{4} \left[\chi(\Omega) - \chi(-\Omega)\right] = \frac12 A^2\Omega\operatorname{Im}\chi(\Omega) $$
In the last equality we've used that real part of $\chi(\omega)$  is even, while imaginary is odd.
This links  $\operatorname{Im} \chi(\omega)$  to dissipation using Kramers-Kronig relations.

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that there is no deeper connection between FD theorem and KK relations apart from the fact that $\chi(\omega)$ appears in both the relations and it represents dissipation.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 I would say that KK relations are just mathematical equalities for a Fourier transform of certain class of functions. So KK don't really say anything about what $Im \chi$ represents. You can show that $Im \chi$ represents dissipation using KK relations (as done in the answer).

Comment: I liked your answer. Particularly the second part. But I think the oddness of the imaginary part of $\chi(\omega)$ follows directly from the defintion of $\chi(\omega)$ which is the Fourier transform of the response function, and reality of theresponse function. One need not use KK relations to show that. I would like to know your comment on this.